# Finding table records based on another table column

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two tables:

```
Orders => [state]
Ads => [title, order_id]

Order has_many Ads
Ad belongs_to Order
```

If I want to find all orders with ads that the title is "AAA" I do:

```
Order.all.joins(:ad).where(title: "AAA")
```

But I want  to find all ads where the orders' state attribute is equals to "XXX". How can I do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In rails you can do it like this:

```
Ad.joins(:order).where(orders: { state: "AAA" })
```

This will produce the following SQL:

```
SELECT ads.*
FROM ads
INNER JOIN orders ON order.id = ads.order_id
WHERE orders.state = 'AAA'
```

Comment: Thank you! I searched and tried something similar but didn't write 'order' in singular form in the first segment and 'orders' in plural for the last one...

Comment: Glad to help :) If you can mark it as correct that would be great :)